# Change dynamic id of an URL

Tags: javascript

I'm looking a way to set with javascript somewhere only the id e.g from a youtube video and to place it automatic in URL. For instance I can make it like this in PHP: ->

```
<?php
$id = 'pOYRLBhYGyc';
?>

<table style="background:url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/  <?php echo "$id" ?>  /0.jpg')no-repeat;
```

Is there any way like this in JS also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to set the background property dynamically.

Checkout a sample in JS Fiddle.

```
<table id="sample" border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The script tag will contain the following script.

```
var videoId = "pOYRLBhYGyc";

$("#sample").attr("background", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/1.jpg");

http://jsfiddle.net/y44n6hao/
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this to a physical link?
e.g `<a href="http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/1.jpg">Link</a>`